# Docker, Mongodb,Spring Boot on Windows getting Connection refused error

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, docker

I am using default docker image of MongoDB and trying to connect using simple spring Boot application on windows box.

mongoDB image is getting stared correctly

[image]

**IP in mongoDB image** 
[image]

I have `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb` in my class path. i am using all spring boot default and only using below property in application.properties.

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=192.168.99.100
```

On application startup getting  **Connection refused: connect** error

Logs

```
019-03-06 06:15:06.096  INFO 4664 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[192.168.99.100:27017], mode=MULTIPLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
2019-03-06 06:15:06.096  INFO 4664 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Adding discovered server 192.168.99.100:27017 to client view of cluster
2019-03-06 06:15:06.356  WARN 4664 --- [           main] o.s.d.m.c.m.BasicMongoPersistentProperty : Customizing field name for id property not allowed! Custom name will not be considered!
2019-03-06 06:15:06.928  INFO 4664 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-03-06 06:15:07.164  INFO 4664 --- [68.99.100:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server 192.168.99.100:27017
```

What i am missing here ?

Comment: Are you a le to connect using comand line or compass?

Comment: Thanks for checking, I am new to Mongo and docker. How i can check that ?

Comment: Here you have instructions https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/

Comment: Yes , i am able to connect using command line

Comment: Maybe in mongod.conf you need to change bind_ip = 0.0.0.0. Default is localhost

Comment: @Niraj The published port of Docker MongoDB is 27071 which should be 27017

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a MongoDB expert, but a moderate Docker user speaking: It looks like you are not publishing the port MongoDB runs by default: **27017**. That's why your spring application could not get a connection and throws this exception:

```
Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server 192.168.99.100:27017
```

So you may try publishing the port by using `-p 27017:27017`when initiating mongo container.